# what is the syntax for aws dms describe_table_statistics in lambda function python?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-dms

I am trying to invoke replication task table statistics in aws lambda function but it's not printing anything. What is wrong with below syntax -

```
filters=[]
    filters.append({'Name':'schema-name', 'Values':['dbo']})
    filters.append({'Name':'table-name', 'Values':['COVID_Testing']})
    print(filters)
    response = client.describe_table_statistics(
        ReplicationTaskArn='arn:aws:dms:eu-west-1:12121212:task:ROIE7878888BEQLE7SW42BTHTWIOL5UYZCHJAJ7I',
        Filters=filters,
        MaxRecords=1
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

with reference to boto3 [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dms.html#DatabaseMigrationService.Client.describe_table_statistics), value of **MaxRecords** must be **minimum 20** and maximum 500;

```
    filters=[]
    filters.append({'Name':'schema-name', 'Values':['dbo']})
    filters.append({'Name':'table-name', 'Values':['COVID_Testing']},)
    print(filters)
    response=client.describe_table_statistics(
    ReplicationTaskArn='arn:aws:dms:eu-west-1:12121212:task:ROIE7878888BEQLE7SW42BTHTWIOL5UYZCHJAJ7I',
    MaxRecords=20,
    Filters=filters
   )
```

Comment: Thanks Amitd, why do we need comma(,) at the 3rd line? And after this I am getting "2020-12-22T15:02:31.389Z 75bdf7ff-36e3-4fc3-9377-7fec9d1fbe41 Task timed out after 308.10 seconds" even though I increased timeout and memory.